# ¿Como puedo ejecutar AJAX después de una función de JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, ajax

Tengo una función en JS que valida los campos de un formulario (lo tome de un ejemplo de la página de bootstrap), lo que necesito hacer es ejecutar mi AJAX después de que los campos estén llenos, intente agregar mi AJAX exactamente después de la función y por algún motivo hace el submit automáticamente al cargar. Luego de eso parece funcionar "normalmente" pero los datos no llegan al AJAX. ¿Que debo hacer para conseguir que funcione correctamente?

```js
/*aqui comienza la funcion que valida los datos*/

(function() {
'use strict';
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
  });
}, false);})(); 

/*aqui termina*/

var descripcion = document.getElementById("medicamento").value;
          
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "agregar_producto.php",
              data: descripcion,
              success: function(data)
                  { 
                  Swal.fire({
                  position: 'top-end',
                  icon: 'success',
                  title: 'Producto añadido',
                  showConfirmButton: false,
                  timer: 1500})
                  },
              error: function(data)
                  {
                  Swal.fire({
                  icon: 'error',
                  title: 'Error al añadir el producto',
                  html: data}); 
                  }
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-body">
<div class="panel-body">
<form id="agregar_producto" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
<label for="medicamento">Medicamento</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="medicamento" placeholder="Medicamento" required>
<div class="invalid-feedback">Debe ingresar el nombre</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-plus mr-2"></i>Agregar producto</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es realmente sencillo, fijate que el código de ajax lo colocas al final del todo:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "agregar_producto.php",
    data: descripcion,
    success: function(data)
    { 
        Swal.fire({
            position: 'top-end',
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Producto añadido',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
        })
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Error al añadir el producto',
            html: data
        }); 
    }
});
```

El problema no es realmente la posición.. si no que:

**Estas llamando a ajax directamente...**

Esta parte de aquí no es una función:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
})
```

Es la `llamada a una función`. por lo cuál ahora es evidente lo que esta pasando, lo que esta pasando es que estas llamando a `ajax` directamente apenas el script cargue, y que pasa?, que el `ajax` de `jQuery` redirige directamente al usuario por defecto, podemos prevenir este comportamiento con un `prevent default` como lo haces aquí:

```
if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Pero te estas olvidando de meter la llamada a `ajax` ahí adentro, es decir, estas previniendo que si el formulario no es valido entonces 'no haga el envio de datos', pero realmente si lo estas haciendo, puesto que mas abajo sin tener en cuenta tu condición ya sea se cumpla o no lo estas llamando:

```
$.ajax({
})
```

La razón por la que después de que se ejecuta y te devuelves para intentar usarlo de nuevo no funciona es porque como he dicho, no se trata de una función, se trata de la `llamada a una función` directamente lo que estas haciendo, por lo cuál la pagina al volver atrás ya tiene cacheada tu envió de datos por medio de `ajax` y determina que no debe volver a hacer el envió si no hasta recargar la pagina (puedes configurar esto en ciertas propiedades de `ajax`).

Mi recomendación es que metas tu llamada a `ajax` en la parte donde compruebas la valides del formulario, o también meter tu llamada dentro de una función, para usarla dentro de tus comprobaciones al llamarla con ciertos parametros.

Comment: Tu aclaración me ayudo, muchas gracias.